# Windows 10 Firewall suddenly blocking ALL incoming connections

Tags: windows-10, networking, firewall

We recently installed several new Windows 10 Pro workstations in a local business. I got a call yesterday that they were having trouble printing from one of the workstations to the network printers. I attempted to remote access the workstation in question, but got no response. I remote accessed one of the other workstations, and attempted to ping the workstation in question, same result.

My first assumption was that the computer was either off, or the network cable had been disconnected. However, when I went onsite, the computer was on, connected, and internet connectivity was normal.

However, the computer was refusing ALL incoming connections, not even allowing a ping. First thought was that the firewall had been changed to public network, but it was on domain network, as it should be. I reset all the firewall rules to default, and even restarted the computer. Same result, outgoing connections fine, inbound completely blocked, even though the firewall rules are set to allow them.

Just to be certain it WAS the firewall, I disabled it for testing, and everything works fine. There are no errors or warnings in any of the log files that I can find, and as far as I could determine, no changes have been made to the system.

So I am at a bit of a loss as to where to look next, since the firewall appears to not be following it's own rules, even after being completely reset.

Comment: Windows Firewall defaults rarely stop printing. Look to see if this computer is somehow on a public network.

Comment: Also check Network Discovery and File/Print sharing as default is to have these disabled.

Comment: The printing issue is because some of the network printers require incoming connections, primarily for scanning.

Comment: Make sure printers and scanning use SMBv2 as SMBv1 is now gone.

Comment: Also, as I mentioned in the post, my immediate expectation on finding the computer powered on and online was for the firewall profile to have been changed to public, as I have encountered that issue many times before. But it was not. And I would have to check, but even public firewall profile allows a ping response, I think.

Comment: I will double check those settings, but as far as network discovery, file print sharing, and smb version, all this was working before, and continues to work on the other two identical workstations. And I don't think any of those settings would effect the ping response or the remote desktop connection.

Comment: Almost all of our customers are on Windows 10 (hundreds of computers) and the basic setups are the same as for Windows 7 (SMB aside).

Comment: We have had some issues with the SMB stuff as well as drivers, they are using some old Ricoh printers that were designed long before Windows 10. But I don't think it relates, the printers not working were a symptom that caused me to get called, not the source of the problem.

Comment: Try to export the firewall rules from a computer that works and import them.

Comment: I will try that tomorrow. Might take a minute to figure, I'm more of a linux guy, I just work on Windows for people. Just wondering though, shouldn't the resetting the firewall have reset all rules to default?